# How to reshape a Teradata table from long to wide format without aggregation?

Tags: sql, teradata

While use of Teradata's PIVOT function has been offered in answers to various questions about converting a long table to wide format, those suggestions involve the use of an aggregation function, a parameter of PIVOT.
Is there a way to reshape/rotate the data *without* aggregation?

Can a table like this ...

| Initial | Name |
| --- | --- |
| A | Abel |
| A | Adriana |
| A | Alberto |
| B | Billy |
| B | Bob |
| C | Carla |
| C | Carlos |
| C | Cesar |
| C | Cristina |

... be turned into the below?

| Initial | Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | Name4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Abel | Adriana | Alberto |  |
| B | Billy | Bob |  |  |
| C | Carla | Carlos | Cesar | Cristina |

Here's the code I used to create the first table in Teradata 16.20:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE MyTab (Initial varchar(1), "Name" varchar(10))
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX(Initial, "Name") ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO MyTab values ('A','Abel');
INSERT INTO MyTab values ('A','Adriana');
INSERT INTO MyTab values ('A','Alberto');
INSERT INTO MyTab values ('B','Billy');
INSERT INTO MyTab values ('B','Bob');
INSERT INTO MyTab values ('C','Carla');
INSERT INTO MyTab values ('C','Carlos');
INSERT INTO MyTab values ('C','Cesar');
INSERT INTO MyTab values ('C','Cristina');

SELECT * FROM MyTab ORDER BY Initial, "Name";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the number of columns, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select initial,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then name end) as name1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then name end) as name2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then name end) as name3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then name end) as name4
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by initial order by name) as seqnum
      from mytab t
     ) t
group by initial;
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you.   
Since I don't know the number of columns, I suppose I'd have to use another language to dynamically determine the number of columns and generate a string to represent the query.

Comment: @MCornejo . . . Exactly.